# fill psql db -> current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Tags: postgresql, postgis

i am trying to get data into a postGIS database. but fail with this error:

```
current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

i did google it but i just cannot find a solution.
First i tried this:

```
shp2pgsql -s 25832:4326 LS489_2023_03_Gebaeude_LSA.shp public.hallebuildings | psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U ffy-selfserving -d postgres
```

same error as above.
Then i tried to do that separately:

```
shp2pgsql -s 25832:4326 LS489_2023_03_Gebaeude_LSA.shp public.hallebuildings >> hallebuildings.sql

 psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U ffy-selfserving -d postgres -f hallebuildings.sql
```

but i always get the same error. What makes it so difficult for me is, when i look at the  log from the db itself, it sais this:

```
2024-03-20 12:57:31 2024-03-20 11:57:31.167 UTC [103] ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
2024-03-20 12:57:31 2024-03-20 11:57:31.167 UTC [103] STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "public"."hallebuildings" ("ags","oi","gfk",geom) VALUES ('15003000','DEST0GGG0004jdsw','31001_2000',ST_Transform('0106000020E86400000100000001030000000100000005000000648693D86CCE2441AE5E9115AE0C564124A7438B6FCE2441575064FBAE0C564165DECC0C7DCE24416E54BA41AE0C5641E571E5507ACE2441016DBE57AD0C5641648693D86CCE2441AE5E9115AE0C5641'::geometry, 4326));
```

running the statement directly in the db works perfectly.

```
INSERT INTO "public"."hallebuildings" ("ags","oi","gfk",geom) VALUES ('15003000','DEST0GGG0004jdsw','31001_2000',ST_Transform('0106000020E86400000100000001030000000100000005000000648693D86CCE2441AE5E9115AE0C564124A7438B6FCE2441575064FBAE0C564165DECC0C7DCE24416E54BA41AE0C5641E571E5507ACE2441016DBE57AD0C5641648693D86CCE2441AE5E9115AE0C5641'::geometry, 4326));
```

where can i look for the problem or does anyone know what it is?

Thanks a lot for ideas!!

Comment: The error is before that message. You had an error and kept inserting anyway which causes this new error until you rollback the transaction